# Authentication with VueX and Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, session, vue.js, vuex

I'm currently using Vue (and VueX) and Laravel Passport. I have my register page working fine, now I've moved into my Login page. All the tutorials and posts I've seen online show a login system where the generated token is stored in localStorage but I've seen also that everybody says we shouldn't store any sensitive data in localStorage, then how should I do it? How can I manage sessions if my frontend (VueX) is separated from my backend (laravel)?

Answer (score 1):

It's alright to store the token in `localStorage`, what you need to do is set the expiry of the token for less time, let's say 2 days.

These lines should be added to *AuthServiceProvider.php*

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(2));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to localStorage? I guess that if it's not secure for 1 week it won't be secure for 1 or 2 days

Comment: You can use cookies but that won't guarantee security as well. The common attack for accessing these token is XSS, it can be prevented tough if all your form have proper validation/filtering.

Comment: Tokens are fine in local storage, People who say they arnt are talking about Year long tokens, An access token which has an exp is fine, just dont ever store usernames and passwords which ive actually seen before.... EVER